# Golden Ratio & Fibonacci - Charles de Gaulle 13-unit two-beamed cross problem.

Tags: linear-algebra, trigonometry, fibonacci-numbers, golden-ratio

Here is the question:

> The [two-beamed cross](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_of_Lorraine), made popular by Charles de Gaulle, is formed from 13 unit squares as shown below. A straight line $BC$ drawn through point $A$ divides the cross in such a way that the total areas on each side of the line are equal. Show that 
>   $$\frac{PB}{BQ} = \phi$$
>
> [where $\phi = 1.618\dots$ is the [golden ratio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_ratio)].

[image]

Cheers,
Axiom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

Let $BQ=x$ and $CF=y$. Then the upper part has area equals to 
$$6.5=5+area(\triangle ABQ)+area(\triangle ACD)=5+\frac x2+\frac{2+y}2.$$
Thus we have $x+y=1$, hence $PB=y$.

On the other hand $\triangle ABE$ and $\triangle ACD$ are similar, so
$$AE:AD = BE:CD,$$
or 
$$x = \frac{1}{2+y}=\frac{1}{3-x}.$$
From there, one should be able to compute $x$ and verify that $\dfrac{1-x}{x}=\phi$.

Comment: Okay, I see where you are getting at. However, could you elaborate on how you found the areas for the two triangles. Why did you divide by 2.

Comment: $\triangle ABQ$ is a right triangle with two legs $1$ and $x$. $\triangle ACD$ is a right triangle with two legs $1$ and $2+y$.